# Linearization of $C^r$ ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory, linearization

Consider the following ODE system
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= x^5 + y^3 = f(x\,,y) \\
\dot{y} &= x^3 - y^5 = g(x\,,y)
\end{align*}
Clearly, $(x\,,y) = (0\,,0)$ is the only fixed point. Linearizing
$$
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
5x^4 & 3y^2 \\
3x^2 & -5y^4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
evaluating at the fixed point will just give a zero matrix. Thus, need to use some other approach to analyze the stability, e.g., Lyapunov function.

However, I can't find any Lyapunov function related to this problem. Since this ODE system is at least $C^3$ in both $x$ and $y$. So I am wondering, for the linearization, is it possible to go all the way to 3rd-order derivative? Maybe something like
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x^3} & \frac{\partial^3f}{\partial y^3} \\
\frac{\partial^3g}{\partial x^3} & \frac{\partial^3g}{\partial y^3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This way the matrix will not be a zero matrix and can find corresponding eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Take $V = x^4 - y^4$ and show that it satisfies the conditions of the [Chetaev instability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chetaev_instability_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= x^5 + y^3 \\
\dot{y} &= x^3 - y^5
\end{align*}

we have

\begin{align*}
x^3\dot{x} &= x^8 + x^3 y^3 \\
y^3\dot{y} &= x^3y^3 - y^8
\end{align*}

and then

$$
\frac 14\frac{d}{dt}(x^4-y^4) = x^8+y^8
$$

analyzing the behavior along a line $y(t) = \alpha x(t)$ we conclude

$$
\frac 14(1-\alpha^4)\frac{d}{dt}x^4 = (1+\alpha^8)x^8
$$

so depending on $\alpha$ the dynamics along $y(t) = \alpha x(t)$ changes concluding that the origin is unstable.

Comment: This does not look like a Lyapunov function, right?

Comment: No it is not a Lyapunov function.

Comment: If $y = k x$, that gives an algebraic equation on $x$ and a finite number of $(x, y)$ points. If the point wasn't $(0, 0)$, the trajectory immediately moves to a line with a different slope. This by itself doesn't tell us anything about the stability.

Comment: There are at least two orbits crossing the origin, for $\alpha = \pm 1$ one has stable flow along it and the other has unstable flow.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the central manifold, considering the system

$$
\cases{
\dot x = f(x,y) = x^5+y^3\\
\dot y = g(x,y) = x^3-y^5
}
$$

and considering $y = h(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^{k+1}$ we have

$$
h'(x)\dot x = \dot y\Rightarrow h'(x)f(x,h(h))=g(x,h(x))
$$

for $n = 6$ we get two solutions:

$$
h_1(x) = -\frac{2 x^7}{27}-\frac{x^5}{6}-\frac{x^3}{3}-x + O(x^9)\\
h_2(x) = -\frac{2 x^7}{27}+\frac{x^5}{6}-\frac{x^3}{3}+x + O(x^9)
$$

Attached a stream flow plot showing the phase plane in light blue and $h_1(x), h_2(x)$ in red. As can easily be verified, $y=h_1(x)$ has stable flow and $h_2(x)$ has unstable flow.

[image]

Comment: My purpose is to show that $(0,0)$ is an unstable equilibrium point. If the origin is stable then all orbits entering a reduced ball containing the origin should enter and remain into that ball. In the present case, at least two constructed orbits are leaving it. Any way. I would appreciate a detailed better explanation.

Comment: Let me clarify my first comment. A center manifold $W^c$ of an equilibrium point $P$ is an invariant manifold tangent to the center eigenspace $E^c$ at $P$ (it has the same dimension as $E^c$, and it is not unique). $E^c$ of a zero matrix is all of $\mathbb R^2$, thus $W^c$ is also $\mathbb R^2$. It's fine to consider a restriction of the vector field to a one-dimensional invariant manifold containing $P$ to prove instability, but the center manifold theory is of no help here, it deals with restricting the problem to $W^c$ but doesn't say anything about the flow on $W^c$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could you suggest some references?

Comment: There is a section on center manifolds in Wiggins, *Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos*.